# global React functions that utilize hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks

I have a function called `scheduleShortcut` that gets used in a couple places throughout an application. Initially, this function was local to the specific components but since it is being used multiple times, I want to refactor this function into a global function.

At first, I tried to do the following:

```
const history = useHistory();
const dispatch = useDispatch();

export const scheduleShortcut = (jobId: number) => {
  dispatch(jobGanttFocus(jobId));
  dispatch(focusJobScheduleFilter(jobId));
  dispatch(toggleScheduleView('jobs'));

  history.push('/schedule');
};
```

However, when I do this, I get an error that says I can't use useHistory or useDispatch unless they are inside a React component or a custom hook. Then, I tried to convert scheduleShortcut into a custom hook in the following way:

```
export const useScheduleShortcut = (jobId: number) => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  dispatch(jobGanttFocus(jobId));
  dispatch(focusJobScheduleFilter(jobId));
  dispatch(toggleScheduleView('jobs'));

  history.push('/schedule');
};
```

This allowed me to utilize useDispatch and useHistory. However, when I try to call this function inside the specific components I need it in, I get a similar error. Basically, it says that I cannot use my custom hook (i.e. `useScheduleShortcut`) inside a callback.

```
<Roster
  jobId={job.id}
  assignWorkers={canAssignWorker ? handleAssignWorkers : undefined}
  scheduleShortcut={() => useScheduleShortcut(jobId)}
/>
```

Is there a way I can get around these errors and use scheduleShortcut as a recyclable function? Or is this in fact not possible since I am using the hooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks in fact must be called on top level, you are breaking that [rule](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)

You could expose(return) a function from hook that could be called as callback afterwards.

i.e.

```
export const useScheduleShortcut = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const dispatchScheduleShortcut = (jobId) => {
    dispatch(jobGanttFocus(jobId))
    dispatch(focusJobScheduleFilter(jobId))
    dispatch(toggleScheduleView('jobs'))
    history.push('/schedule')
  }

  return {
    dispatchScheduleShortcut
  }
};
```

and then use it as

```
const { dispatchScheduleShortcut } = useScheduleShortcut()

return (
  <Roster
    jobId={job.id}
    assignWorkers={canAssignWorker ? handleAssignWorkers : undefined}
    scheduleShortcut={() => dispatchScheduleShortcut(jobId)}
  />
)
```

Comment: I think theres's a piece missing from your answer. How would I pull dispatchScheduleShortcut from the custom hook import?

Comment: @JevonCochran check updated answer